# STM32F10x writing uint8 value to gpio register over uint8 pointer

Tags: gpio, uint8t, stm32f1

So I have to port code from a STM32F4xx device to a STM32F10x Device.
Everything went well and I made huge progress in no time. But then it hit me!
At one point in the software there is the following definition

`#define BYTE_GPIO  (*((__IO uint8_t *)(GPIOE_BASE + 0x0C + 1)))`

which obviously defines an access to upper byte of the GPIOE ODR register.
While this works fine (as I was told) in the STM32F4x devices as they support byte access to this register, it is not with the stm32F10x devices. This is also stated in the RM:

> These bits can be read and written by software and can be accessed in Word mode only.

First I neglected this statement and just went for a try: the code compiles fine without any errors or warnings and even the writes to the upper byte of the GPIOE will be performed well, but soon I discovered that the lower byte of GPIOE is affected by any write to the BYTE_GPIO, too.
As this obviously is not usable, I have to find an other solution.
But as I dont want to change a lot of application-layer code I'd rather fix this definition some how. Unfortunately I do not see how.
So I'm open for idea.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify the byte you need the sequence of instructions.

```
inline __attribute__((always_inline)) void SetByte(volatile uint32_t *reg, int byte, uint8_t value)
{
    uint32_t regval = *reg;
    regval &= ~(0xff << (byte * 8));
    regval |= value << (byte * 8);
    *reg = regval;
}
```

and usage

```
SetByte(&GPIOE -> ODR, 1, val);
```

Comment: P__J__ thanks for your answer unfortunately thats not what I am looking for. I know your solution. I would have written it like ```GPIOE->ODR = GPIOE->ODR & 0x00FF | byte << 8;```but like I said I dont want to change the application layer code. So I'm looking for a way of changing the definition

Comment: My goal is something that I can write ```GPIO_BYTE = x;``` where x is some uint8_t val.